# cantidad de digitos en todos los numeros ingresados c++

Tags: c++, array, contador

me dieron el siguiente enunciado: Escribir un programa que permita al usuario ingresar números enteros positivos (los números ingresados no deben almacenarse). Al finalizar, informar la cantidad de veces que apareció cada dígito (del 0 al 9) en todos los números. Ejemplo: Si el usuario ingresa los números 1156, 23, 73364, 988, 1003, 5, se debe informar que el 0 apareció 2 veces, el 1 apareció 3 veces, el 2 apareció 1 vez, el 3 apareció 4 veces, etc

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
void cuentadigitos(int n, int digitos[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        digitos[ i ] = 0;
    }

    n = abs(n);
    while(n > 0) {
        digitos[n % 10] += 1;
        n /= 10;
        
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        if (digitos[i] > 0 ) {
            printf( "%d aparece %d veces.\n", i, digitos[i] );
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    #define MAX 20
    int numeros[MAX];
    int n, ingreso;

    cout << "cuantos num: " ; cin >> ingreso;
    for (int i = 0; i < ingreso; i++){
    cout << "Ingrese numeros: "; cin >> n;
    cuentadigitos(n, numeros);
  }
return 0;
}
```

Ejemplo de lo que devuelve:

cuantos num: 2

Ingrese numeros: 469 
4 aparece 1 veces. 
6 aparece 1 veces. 
9 aparece 1 veces. 
Ingrese numeros: 112 
1 aparece 2 veces. 
2 aparece 1 veces.

El codigo "cumple" su funcion, pero lo que yo quiero lograr es primero ingresar todos los numeros, y que cuente los digitos que aparecen en todos los ingresados, no uno a uno. ¿que deberia corregir? desde ya muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente agrega un arreglo en el que guardes los números, los lees primero y luego llamas la función con cada uno.

El problema de que no se acumulan los dígitos contados anteriormente es porque cada vez que llamas a la función estableces cada elemento del arreglo en 0:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    digitos[i] = 0;
}
```

Solo tendrás que inicializar el arreglo, puedes hacerlo con ese mismo código pero al inicio de la función main donde se ejecute una sola vez o puedes usar un inicializador de lista:

```
// Puedes designar cada elemento
int digitos[10] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

// O que todos los elementos sean inicializados a 0 si no indicas ninguno.
int digitos[10] = { };
```

Por cierto, puedes crear una variable de tipo `unsigned int` para que solo permita números positivos. Tampoco creo que quieras imprimir la cantidad de los dígitos cada vez que llames la función así que puedes mover esa parte a otro lugar.

También sugiero que seas consistente y uses todas funciones de C++, a menos que no tenga una función similar. Por ejemplo, `cout` que es de C++ y `printf` que es de C, ambas sirven para imprimir en consola.

---

El código te quedaría así.

```
void cuentaDigitos(unsigned int n, int digitos[]) {
    while (n > 0) {
        digitos[n % 10] += 1;
        n /= 10;
    }
}

void mostrarDigitos(int digitos[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        if (digitos[i] > 0) {
            cout << i << " aparece " << digitos[i] << " veces.\n";
        }
    }
}

int main() {
#define MAX 20
    int digitos[10] = {};
    unsigned int numeros[MAX];
    int ingreso;

    cout << "Cuantos numeros: ";
    cin >> ingreso;
    for (int i = 0; i < ingreso; i++) {
        cout << "Ingrese un numero: ";
        cin >> numeros[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ingreso; i++) {
        cuentaDigitos(numeros[i], digitos);
    }

    mostrarDigitos(digitos);
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##lVJNb4MwDL3nV1idplLRbUD3Da00bZcddp@0coggZZaKQQS6Q8VvZwkQoJV2mC9WYvu9l@dEeX4V7TklTXOBFO2rWECAmSwLwdMNqyRSAsRTIXMeCZBl7DN2yDCGqBJU8jdMsMykVZHEhEQMSCXQsk1xV/sKF3BkoOLnG/cCLIINOOZOh2kkuATXCcFeg@sPVYIbdXa6i5rVPX@qRfLCCDgl7LB3WQFtAWENjq9SoIHAtnFKjzuwzCiG5@J0RFlVQhBogABmwHNeCOXGTB8nk23xoCryekuz8QX1KF2rSTmSpSkuYrFDEvDx8gme0zZNn6GtWMOx7oBOHa5SUagWNRn6w6DaVSFkpjY0FT17rTgpPDP0DL20CNUmNuPUX5aZBkDbnjozELy3DUJJ7DkGigmNkYyh2eQUY76lea/7XxJOPuFIsTQmLgxZm87@zNhTN82Kua7reSvm3d4/Osxd3T08sV8).